# reactivesearch: placing result count text on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactivesearch

I presume that putting `<span id="rtxt"></span>` in the DOM and then doing this

```
onResultStats={function (time_taken, total_results) { $('#rtxt').text('Found ' + total_results + ' products (' + time_taken + 'ms).'); return null; }}
```

in the `ResultList` is bad.

How is one *supposed* to put the results stats where one wants them?

(Would be nice to add some number formatting too.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is store the `time_taken` and `total_results` in your component's state and then render them in any way you want. Note that `onResultStats` is actually a render prop and is used inside the `render` function internally which would cause an infinite loop if you do a `setState` without any checks. There is a proposal for a better API specs [here](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/392). For now you could update your component's state after checking if the `time_taken` is different. Example:

```
onResultStats={(total, time) => {
  if (this.state.total !== total) {
    this.setState({ total, time })
  }
  return null;
}
```

Now that you have it in `state` you could render it in anyway that suits your needs.